# Extract list of titles from iPhoto album

Tags: photos.app

I have a large collection of photos on iPhoto (not Photos) and am currently in the process of mounting them in photoviewer on my own website. I have an HTML markup template in an Excel file and have been filling a title column I created by hand, copying and pasting from the iPhoto album.

This is fine for an album of a couple of dozen photos, but I am now faced with a couple of albums of several hundred photos, so I was wondering if there was any way of extracting this from the metadata in iPhotos.

I went into ‘Pictures’, located the ‘iPhoto Library’ did a ‘Show Package Contents’ and opened the ‘AlbumData.xml’ file in a text editor and then in Property List Editor. However the xml format does not make it easy to locate a particular album and then the data for each image is listed separately.

I suppose I could export the files using filenames and then cat them on the Unix command line, but they’d be sorted alphabetically and duplicate names would be altered.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: I'm migrating my own albums from Mac iPhoto, just discovered the AlbumData.xml file. Do you get anywhere with your scenario? I'm going to write a .NET Core library to read this xml file format and provide and index to all the content allowing users to extract the metadata and original master file. If you need this still let me know.

Comment: @StephenYork — In the end I did it the tedious and stupid way just to get the job done. So, thanks for your offer, but I don't really need to do it again.